# Debugging Asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

My project has 4 layers i need to debug from UI to DAL ,,but when i am debugging,its going only in UI,,can any one tell how can idebug up to Dal

Answer (score 1):

Are the layers all in separate Solutions?  If so use the refrences to the Build\Debug directories to be able to step through.

Also make sure all projects are set the DEBUG under Build-> Configuration Manager

Comment: i didnt get you,,can you clear the things i am new one to Asp.net

Comment: layers are in different solutions

Comment: when i googled i found System.Diagonostic.debugger.Launch will split layers for debugging

Answer (score 0):

Does your Solution contain all 4 projects?

Is your ASP.NET application referencing your DLLs as Binaries or as Projects? (check by right-clicking on the web project and selecting Properties | References) Needs to be "Project".

Are all four assemblies/projects set to "Debug" output?

Comment: i didnt get you,,can you clear the things i am new one to Asp.net
layers are in different solutions

Comment: When i opened properties Build section the out path is like this way
bin\

Comment: when i googled i found System.Diagonostic.debugger.Launch will split layers for debugging

Comment: A typical Web Application in Visual Studio will have 1xweb site and any number of DLLs (representing DAL, etc.). These will sit within a single Solution. (A Solution has can have 1 or more Projects). For simplicity, keep your projects in same solution for debugging.

Comment: Also, it's not the path you're interested in (Leave as bin\\). Right click on Web Site Project, click Properties, click References in left pane and your dependant projects should be on the right hand side, added as Project (not bin/DLL)

Comment: here in reference paths,,everything is blank one folder option is browsing and adding,what to do here

Comment: In Reference Paths, click "Add references" to add your other Projects if they are not already present.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just referencing the dll's for the individual layers, make sure you copy the appropriate pdb files for the dlls as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just open all your projects first and try, it will work.